# Why does Eclipse not allow me to create sub folders correctly?

Tags: java, eclipse, structure, directory

When I'm trying to create a folder structure in my Resources folder, Eclipse messes it up.

For example I have an image stored in `/Resources/Graphics/SomeFolder/example.gif`

In the `Package/Project Explorer` I have then an empty package `Graphics` and a different package called `Graphics.SomeFolder`. Now I can't load the image when I try to access is with the normal path.

For clarification I created this folder structure `\Resources\graphics\images\subfolder\image.gif` and this is what Eclipse makes of it:

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [666kb.com](http://666kb.com/i/cm9j1lc3n76biybxp.gif))</sub>

Comment: Show us exactly what you're doing. Odds are that your "normal path" is incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean by load the image? Use it from within your code or viewing it outside your program?

Comment: And also refresh/clean your project, maybe Eclipse does not know your image is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because your `Resources` folder is created as a `"source folder"`. So it is displaying subfolders as a package structure. Define your `Resources` folder as a normal folder using `"New -> Folder"`

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by [Sanjeev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22117293/3129992) (use the context menu item "New"->"Folder" in resource folder) does not work for me in Eclipse 2022-12 (4.26.0).
I found that to display folders instead of packages, you need to set the Excluded filter as a pattern `**`. To do this, in the "Java Build Path" select the "Excluded" item in the properties of the resources folder, then click on the "Edit" button and in the window that appears add the "**" pattern to the "Exclusion patterns".

[image: Add exclusion pattern to resource folder]

[image: Resource subfolders as packages] [image: Resource subfolders as folder]